# Need to fill a brochure preview in real time with a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

We have a web application that uses asp.net and VB.net for the code behind. I am learning javascript.

I have 2 div's side by side. The first div contains ASP dropdowns and texboxes such as (camp name, registration fee, start and end dates).

On the second div, I have a preview of those new camp that is being created, with labels that indicate the camp name, start and end dates etc on it.

My question is, how can I use JavaScript (ajax and JQuery are fine also) to fill in the information entered on the first div to the second div in real time?

For example when somebody enters the camp name on the first div and then clicks outside or tabs out of the camp name text-box, the appropriate label on the brochure div gets filled out?

In other words, when the Camp name text-box loses focus, the Camp name label on the second div should get filled.

It would be preferable if I used as little code behind as possible and accomplish this entirely on the client side.

Comment: client side is good choice for this, and do this on keypressdown/ keypressup event instead of focus?....so that way you can easily show when user typing up also...  Include what you tried till now, we can help you futher

Comment: Look up `onchange event` This will do the thing for you. If you make some example code and it won't work or do what you expect it to do, post it here and we'll take a look. That's the SO MO.

Comment: Onchange event worked great for dropdownlists that were static, but doesn't work with asp:DropDownLists. Is this by design? I'm assuming it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/5922z9mm/) for this

Add two div with One textbox and another one with Span

```
<div id="myExample1">
    Div 1 <input id="myInputText1" type="text" name="inputBox1" />
    </div>
<br/>
<div id="myExample2">
    Div 2 <span id="myText2" type="text" name="myText2" />
</div>
```

Now use this jquery code to achieve desired result as user type in see textbox value in span

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#myInputText1').keyup(function() {
          $('#myText2').html($(this).val());             
   });
});
```

Comment: This did it for me. Thank you @Piyush Sorry I tool so long to mark as answer, got side tracked.